# Centering a un-ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to center an un-ordered list without the bullet points using CSS. And no matter what I've tried the list is being centered including the bullet points.

[image]

Even though you can not see the bullet points they are still being included when I try to center the list.

```css
.nav ul {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px red solid;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav li {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Gallery</li>
  <li>Contact
    <li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `ul` needs `padding: 0;`. Open your console, inspect the `<ul>`, see the box model. It’s immediately clear that it has some padding on the left.

Comment: This is not a good question lol -- just saying bro!

Comment: @Xufox cheers, I wonder why there was padding there to begin with? I never wrote it in my code.

Comment: @LearnerBeware It’s a browser default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML ordered and unordered lists normally have a default padding or margin for indentation. This is included in the browser's default style sheet.

Some browsers apply `padding-left`. Others use `margin-left`.

The W3C recommends `margin-left: 40px` ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html)).

When you center an HTML list, the left-side padding/margin will be centered along with the content, positioning the content center-right.

Try this:

```
ul { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation that really clears things up for me

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Gallery</li>
    <li>Contact
      <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav ul {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px red solid;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```